# Log4j2 LogManager.getLogger() with Spring

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I know that a log4j logger instance is supposed to be created through LogManager.getLogger() that does some reflection magic to detect the calling class hence the name which is important for specific log level configuration.
But what if I don't like the logger to be created manually and want it to be injected using spring like all the other dependencies of the class? When doing that the calling class is of course not the one that has the dependency to the logger, it is spring (some factory). So detecting the class name doesn't work anymore.
The question can even be more simple: Does the log4j2 class name detection somehow work with IoC?

```
public class SomeClassWithDependencies {
    private final DependencyOne dependencyOne;
    private final Logger logger;

    @Inject
    public SomeClassWithDependencies(
              DependencyOne dependencyOne,
              Logger logger) { // <- this is created by spring and operates on the name of some spring factory instead of SomeClassWithDependencies
        this.dependencyOne = dependencyOne;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I actually realized that a logger should be kind of considered as a compositional dependency. So now I'm always creating a logger instance manually per class. In case I wanna hide the concrete logging technology I could inject some LoggerFactory and still create it inside the constructor to make the magic reflection stuff working.